# Flask does not load configuration

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I am facing trouble with loading configuration in Flask.

```
from config import config, DevelopmentConfig, TestingConfig, ProductionConfig

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])    # Doesnot load configuration
    app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)    # Loads configuration succesfully.
```

I have checked the type of config[config_name] etc. They are just fine.

**config file** is given as follow. There are no issues with import, object types. If passed statically everything works fine. 
'host'='serverip' is intentional.

Also, this problem does not arise when I try to connect to db using SQLAlchemy but in case of MongoDB, it does not update MONGODB_SETTINGS in application settings.

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

from helper.helper_functions import generate_secret_key

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or generate_secret_key()
    SSL_DISABLE = False

    @staticmethod
    def init_app(app):
        pass


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
   DEBUG = True
    MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
        'DB': 'development_db',
        'host': 'localhost',
       'port': 27017
    }


class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
    MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
        'DB': 'testing_db',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 27017
    }


class ProductionConfig(Config):
    MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
        'DB': 'production_db',
        'host': 'server_ip',
        'port': 27017,       # default =27017
        # other settings...
    }

    @classmethod
    def init_app(app):
        Config.init_app(app)

config = {
    'development': DevelopmentConfig,
    'testing': TestingConfig,
    'production': ProductionConfig,
    'default': TestingConfig,
}
```

**Interestingly**.

```
app.config.update(MONGODB_SETTINGS={'DB':'testing_db'})   # works
settings = dict([('db', 'testing_db')])
app.config.update(MONGODB_SETTINGS=settings)    # Does not work
```

Also, when I try to load configuration from configuration file using the other method offered by Flask-Config.

```
conf_name = 'test-config.py'
app.config.pyfile(conf_name)    # Doesnot load the configuration from the file.
app.config.pyfile(''+conf_name)    # Doesnot load the configuration from the file.
app.config.pyfile('test-config.py')    #successfully loads the configuration from file.
```

Comment: Can you share the source code for config? We need to see how DevelopmentConfig and the other are defined.

Comment: How are you invoking this?

Comment: Using Flask-script manager and also for running unittests as well. I have spend quite sometime in testing everything else. It works fine. The problem is specifically at this point which I mentioned in the question.

Comment: what happens when you try: `app.config.from_object(config['development'])` ?

Comment: @rbp doesn't work :(

Comment: i don't believe this is all the running code. `print dir(config['development']), dir(DevelopmentConfig)`

Comment: @rbp Yes, this is not all the running code but I have checked every other bit of the code and the problem is only here. As I mentioned it works fine with SQLAlchemy but gives the issues only with MongoDB.
For your last comment.



    print dir(config['development']), dir(DevelopmentConfig) --> ['MONGODB_SETTINGS', 'SECRET_KEY', 'SSL_DISABLE', 'DEVELOPMENT', 'WTF_CSRF_ENABLED', '__doc__', '__module__', 'init_app']
['MONGODB_SETTINGS', 'SECRET_KEY', 'SSL_DISABLE', 'DEVELOPMENT', 'WTF_CSRF_ENABLED', '__doc__', '__module__', 'init_app']

Comment: note that 'db' has to be in uppercase. also `print config['development']['MONGODB_SETTINGS]','DevelopmentConfig['MONGODB_SETTINGS']`. the only other thing I can suggest to you is to reduce this to a simple example that only includes the code above

Comment: @rbp config['development'].MONGODB_SETTINGS --> {'host': 'localhost', 'DB': 'development_db', 'port': 27017}           
DevelopmentConfig.MONGODB_SETTINGS ==>{'host': 'localhost', 'DB': 'development_db', 'port': 27017}

Comment: then your bug is not here. i am going to flag this question to close because you've categorically proven that there is no difference between `config['development']['MONGODB_SETTINGS]'` and `'DevelopmentConfig['MONGODB_SETTINGS']‌` either in form or substance.

Comment: @rbp Exactly, that is the purpose of this question that everything works flawlessly individually but does not work when its used in the function as explained. I have mentioned this in the initial comments as well.

Comment: @rbp Another thing you should notice is that config['development'] returns an object of Config class, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem may lie in the fact that you are giving a Python object to `app.config.from_object` when it expects a string. From the docs:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('yourapplication.default_settings')
app.config.from_envvar('YOURAPPLICATION_SETTINGS')
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#configuring-from-files

So in your case you may want do something like:

```
app.config.from_object('your_app.config.{}'.format(config_name))
```

where `config_name` matches the object in your config.py.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately it does not work. 
Also, app.config.from_object(config[config_name])  works perfectly when I use SQLAlchemy but in case of MONGODB, it does not update the MONGODB _SETTINGS.

Comment: Well remember that this string in from_object correlates directly to the object name - so you need `your_app.config.DevelopmentConfig` for example. I've taken your code and created a small test and it does work when setting it like - if needed print out the config_name or better yet drop into the debugger to make sure it works.

Comment: Sure, I will use the debugger. I have tried printing the variable etc. The problem mainly arises when it does not change the MONGODB_SETTINGS in the config. I have another related question which aligns more with your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808010/flask-monogengine-configuration