# app_config[config_name] getting KeyError null value for flask environment

Tags: python, flask, config

I am creating employee management software in python in flask environement by referring this code

https://github.com/littlewonder/squadmaster

i have installed pip , flask an other relevant libraries .i have also created virtal environment .I put the project folder inside the flask as well .

folder structure in side flask folder is like this

[image]

when  i tried to tun run.py . it gives me error

```
app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name]) KeyError: None
```

this is my run.py file

```
import os

from app import create_app

config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG')
app = create_app(config_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

i have faced similar question

[Flask does not load configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811823/flask-does-not-load-configuration)

i have implemented its solution and use these strings

```
app.config.from_object('myapplication.default_settings')

app.config.from_object('my_app.config.{}'.format(config_name))
```

I have set FLASK_CONFIG as in upper as documented 
I have setup the FLASK_CONFIG as environment variable in system build path . but it results me to error as KeyError = "full path" .

i have also tried to set 
FLASK_CONFIG ='development'
and FLASK_CONFIG =DevelopmentConfig

as mentioned in config.py

```
app_config = {
    'development': DevelopmentConfig,
    'production': ProductionConfig
}
```

what else can i tried  to get a hint whats going wrong . need some suggestion

Comment: How did you set FLASK_CONFIG and then start run.py?

Comment: i set as environment variable . by that it gives me keyerror="environment path"

Comment: But in your question there is `KeyError: None`. It is not clear to me what code do you actually run and what code you have only tried.

Comment: yes KeyError: None when i didnt set "flask_config"  as environment variable .  when i set "flask_config"  as environment variable .i got KeyError = "flask_config environment variable path"

Answer (score 4):

The first problem can be solved with a reasonable default:

```
config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default'
```

or just `os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG', 'default')`, where the meaning of the default can be set in config.app_config

```
app_config = {
    'development': DevelopmentConfig,
    'production': ProductionConfig,
    'default': ProductionConfig
}
```

The `app_config` maps a name to an object with configuration. A reference ina  string form is also allowed, but you can pass the object directly to `.from_object`):

```
app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
```

The configuration data stored e.g. `DevelopmentConfig` must contain the data items as its attributes. It can be a class.

Comment: I get a error at this line app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
exacly, so if I pass it like that, why do I get KeyError: None?

Comment: @FeridSejdović I don't know from such a short description. You could add some debug  print statements to see what is assigned to `config_name` or other variables involved.

Comment: Simply, it says KeyError: None Just take a look at this: https://www.google.com/amp/s/scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-crud-web-app-with-python-and-flask-part-one/amp

Comment: @FeridSejdović But that code differs from my answer. There is a simple `os.getenv` without a default. I guess `FLASK_CONFIG` not set in the environment is probably responsible for the KeyError.

Comment: I know Sir, I was asking about that specific line, I am new in the Python world, thanks anyway. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux first type:
export FLASK_ENV=development